# Java Scanner Support in c9.io?

Tags: java

## EDIT

In C9, You have to configure your own runner/builder for Java. If asked for, I'll post my runner/builder if necessary.

I looked up an example script for using Scanner in Java. I use a site called [Cloud9](http://c9.io) for my code, scripts, etc., and I seem to have run into an issue.

I don't know if Cloud9 doesn't support it, but I got this example code for using Scanner, and it throws some weird error at me.

## The Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GetInputFromUser
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int a;
      float b;
      String s;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string");
      s = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered string "+s);

      System.out.println("Enter an integer");
      a = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered integer "+a);

      System.out.println("Enter a float");
      b = in.nextFloat();
      System.out.println("You entered float "+b);   
   }
}
```

## The Console

```
Running GetInputFromUser.java                                                                                                                                                                                  

Enter a string                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found                                                                                                                                     
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)                                                                                                                                                       
        at GetInputFromUser.main(GetInputFromUser.java:14)
```

Is it something to do with the C9 IDE or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I know eclipse IDE's don't properly handle console input perhaps C9 doesn't either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does Cloud9 handle standard input? Because that's the error you get when Scanner hits end-of-file:

```
$ java GetInputFromUser </dev/null
Enter a string
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at GetInputFromUser.main(GetInputFromUser.java:14)
```